# changing brtfs disk issues

Tags: linux, btrfs, raid

I just started to have bad magic issue...

currently (and sadly) I have a raid 1 btrfs on:

btrfs fi show   /dev/nvme2n1p4
Label: none  uuid: beecd604-caa8-45a5-b3cb-f23389e8df97
Total devices 2 FS bytes used 1.16TiB
devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 1.34TiB path /dev/nvme2n1p4
devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 1.34TiB path /dev/nvme0n1

I would like to move it to a partition on nvme0n1p4 but it seems impossible without a new disk ?

any idea how to proceed ?